# See if event occurs (true or false) on each day on specific month

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to highlight the days on my jQuery datepicker calendar which are associated with an event.  In my database I have many events with a date field. So if January is selected on the datepicker, I want to check the database table to see if:

January 1st: Is there an event (true/false)
January 2nd: Is there an event (true/false)
January 3rd: Is there an event (true/false)
... and so on.

I guess I could just create a loop to create 31 queries to do the job. Is there's more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT datefield, bool_field
FROM table
WHERE (whatever)
GROUP BY EXTRACT (DAY FROM datefield)
```

See the documentation for [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) for other possibilities (like day of week).